# P value equal to 0.000 in every test: how is it possible?

Tags: spss, normalization

I have 8 variables for which I have to examine whether they have a normal distribution or not. There are 270 observations for each variable. I've run a normality test on SPSS for each variable and all the 8 p-values are at 0.000, meaning none of them is normally distributed.

Consequently, for each variable, I've tried to normalize it in any possible way (e.g. using square root, log, inverse log, power of 2, power of 3, ecc) and then run another normality test. EVERY normality test for every variable (even after normalization attempts) returns 0.000 as p-value. It is really strange also because some of the histograms really look like normal distributions.

What's going on? Is it possible I cannot normalize data?!

PS The normalization attempts have mainly been focused on "reversing" the variable since distributions seem to be negatively skewed.

Comment: Two options. One: you are doing something wrong with the software. To check this, try running the test on some data you know is normal and make sure you don't get a small p-value. Two: your data simply isn't exactly normal. This is actually a pretty usual situation. There's no reason that data should be normal. Lots of it isn't at all, and even when it is, it's unlikely to be *exactly* normal, and with a largish sample size (like you have), a statistical test will detect this deviation as significant. Remember that p-values don't measure effect size.

Comment: $P = 0.000$ is not to be meant literally. It will mean $P < 0.0005$. In practice it means that your sample size is large enough for deviation from normality to be confirmed; that doesn't mean that the deviation is important. But don't treat transformations like a shotgun. Square and square root can't be both plausible. Show us some normal quantile plots and there may be good advice on whether normality looks adequate or there is a helpful transformation in reach. Negative skew sometimes calls for squaring but all values must be non-negative. Skewness and kurtosis sometimes are helpful.

Comment: The biggest question is what analysis follows this. For example, regression and similar techniques don't require that any of the variables concern have marginal normal distributions.

Comment: If you have just a few ties in the data, then any (decent) test of normality of any transformation of the data ought to have a tiny p-value.

Comment: This will be followed by a factor analysis and a check for the Cronbach's alphas. I'll try to explain a little bit further: this data comes from a questionnaire posed to professional investors concerning the likelihood they would invest in certain startups. Answers are from 1 to 7, in particular for the first question answers are: 1 26x, 2 34x, 3 40x, 4 45x, 5 57x, 6 50x, 7 17x. Would you be able to find a transformation that makes these data "normal"?

Comment: That would be impossible.  Although there are transformations for which a Normal distribution might, for some purposes, be a crude approximation, the transformed data will always look significantly non-normal according to any reasonable test.  Your getting ahead of yourself: you need to focus first on what you're trying to accomplish rather than on the issue of how your data appear to be distributed.